# Changing the content of a label after a checkbox is selected in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a label that is coded like this that contains text that is set upon running the program.

```
label_text = StringVar()
label = Label(window,textvariable=label_text)
label_text.set("Off")
```

I also have a checkbox;

```
var= IntVar()
Check= Checkbutton(window,text = "On",variable = var,onvalue = 1,offvalue = 0)
```

These are both packed like this:

```
label.pack()
Check.pack(side="left")
```

When the checkbox is checked, I want to have the label change text to "On", 
something like this.

```
if var.get()==1:
    label_text.set("On")
```

The text remains at Off when I check the checkbox. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `label_text.configure(text="On")`

Comment: @MrFregg that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of updating the label text when the checkbutton state changes.

One possibility is to make the label and the checkbutton share the same `StringVar` and set the onvalue/offvalue of the checkbutton to "On"/"Off". That way, when the state of the checkbutton changes, the text of the label is automatically updated.

```
from tkinter import StringVar, Tk, Label, Checkbutton

window = Tk()

label_text = StringVar()
label = Label(window, textvariable=label_text)
label_text.set("Off")

check= Checkbutton(window,  text="On", variable=label_text,
                   onvalue="On", offvalue="Off")

label.pack()
check.pack(side="left")

window.mainloop()
```

If for some reason you really want the onvalue/offvalue of the checkbutton to be 0/1, you can pass a function to the `command` option of the checkbutton. This function will change the text of the label depending on the state of the checkbutton.

```
from tkinter import StringVar, Tk, Label, Checkbutton, IntVar

def update_label():
    if var.get() == 1:
        label_text.set("On")
    else:
        label_text.set("Off")

window = Tk()

label_text = StringVar()
label = Label(window, textvariable=label_text)
label_text.set("Off")

var = IntVar()
check= Checkbutton(window,  text="On", variable=var,
                   onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=update_label)

label.pack()
check.pack(side="left")

window.mainloop()
```